# Why am I still getting undefined returned from the array.find() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I seem to keep getting **undefined** returned from the **find()** method attached to my **products** array. I am not sure why. The condition in my callback function should be true. Can anyone tell me what might be the cause?

Please let me know if I need to add more info. Thanks

````
    ``` html
    <img class = "image" id = "image" src = " " alt = "activeimage">
    <div class = "button" id = "btn1"></div>
    <span id = "colorlabel"> </span>
    
    <button id = "addtocartBtn" type = "button">Add To Cart</button>
    ```
    
    ``` js
    $("#btn1").on("click", function(){
    $('#image').attr("src", "assets/chad.jpg");
    $('#colorlabel').text("Black/Black/Black");
    ```
    ``` js
    let addToCart = document.querySelector('button#addtocartBtn');
    let products = [
      {
        name: "Black/Black/Black",
        tag: 'black/black/black',
        price: 21.99,
        inCart: 0
        },
      {
        name: "Navy/Navy/Navy",
        tag: 'navy/navy/navy',
        price: 21.99,
        inCart: 0
        },
      {
        name: "Off-White/Off-White/Off-White",
        tag: 'off-white/off-white/off-white',
        price: 21.99,
        inCart: 0
          }
         ];
    let myProduct = products.find(element => {
      let spancolorLabel = document.querySelector('span#colorlabel');
      let spanTextContent = spancolorLabel.textContent;
      let stringify = JSON.stringify(element.name);
      return (stringify == spanTextContent);
    })
    addToCart.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(myProduct);
    })
    ```
````

Comment: I had a go at cleaning up your code formatting but I think you didn't quite add everything correctly. Could you please review it?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I've been going over it, does it matter that my callback function is comparing variables? I tested the add method on variable vs. primitive data types, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of '#btn1' use '#addtocartBtn' to select the correct button.

Also you don't have to use JSON.stringify, just use the element.name to compare string with string, that function returns the element.name like this "&quot;Black/Black/Black&quot;"

Answer (score 0):

Better try this below code,

```
let myProduct = products.find(element => {   
  let colorLabel = document.querySelector('span#colorlabel');   
  let spanTextContent = spancolorLabel.textContent;   
  let stringify = element.name;  // Here is the change   
  return (stringify == spanTextContent); 
});
```

You are trying to stringify a string value, so it might be comparing the ""value"" instead of "value".

Comment: I gave it a shot, but still no luck.